# Flip the x-axis of a D3 Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: d3.js, charts

Chapter 11 of "[Interactive Data Visualization for the Web](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch11.html#_stack_layout)" shows how to create stacked bar charts with the [D3.js library](http://d3js.org). The example produces an upside down chart with the bars attached to the top of the x-axis.

[image: D3 Stacked Bar Chart with bars attached to the top.]

Flipping the chart and attaching them to the bottom is left as an exercise for the reader.

Given this starting point:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var w = 500;
  var h = 300;

  var dataset = [[ { x: 0, y: 5 }, { x: 1, y: 4 }, { x: 2, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 7 }, { x: 4, y: 23 }],
    [ { x: 0, y: 10 }, { x: 1, y: 12 }, { x: 2, y: 19 }, { x: 3, y: 23 }, { x: 4, y: 17 } ],
    [ { x: 0, y: 22 }, { x: 1, y: 28 }, { x: 2, y: 32 }, { x: 3, y: 35 }, { x: 4, y: 43 } ]];

  var stack = d3.layout.stack();
  stack(dataset);

  var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(d3.range(dataset[0].length)).rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);

  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
        return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; });
      })])
      .range([0, h]);

  var colors = d3.scale.category10();

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

  var groups = svg.selectAll("g").data(dataset).enter().append("g")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors(i); });

  var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d; })
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) { return xScale(i); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.y0); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return yScale(d.y); })
      .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand());
</script>
```

What needs to be done to flip the chart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I came up with involves three changes:

1. Change the yScale .range from:

   ```
   .range([0, h]);
   ```

   to:

   ```
   .range([h, 0]);
   ```
2. Change the rect "y" .attr from:

   ```
   .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.y0); })
   ```

   to:

   ```
   .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.y0) + yScale(d.y) - h; })
   ```
3. Change the rect "height" .attr from:

   ```
   .attr("height", function(d) { return yScale(d.y); })
   ```

   to:

   ```
   .attr("height", function(d) { return h - yScale(d.y); })
   ```

With those changes applied, the stacks attach to the bottom and still maintain their relative sizes.

[image: D3 Stacked Bar Chart with bars attached to the bottom.]